# get contact path in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have found several way to set the context path, but didn't found anyway to get the context path in the spring boot application. There is one way to get it through @Value("server.contextPath"), but I am looking for more elegant way to get hold of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the context path in controller as:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getUsers")
public String getUsers(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in the Request and use `request.getContextPath` if you'd like.

Check the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) to see if this would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the contextPath within the application.properties file.

something like this:

```
server.contextPath=/yourChosenContextPath
```